# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error unzip(path, list = TRUE) en swirl?

Tags: r, rstudio

Llevo poco tiempo trasteando con R, y me he encontrado con un problema, parto de la base de que es mi primera experiencia en este tipo de programas y no comprendo muchas cosas, el problema es el siguiente:

Estoy intentando realizar un curso de [statseducation](http://statseducation.com/Introduction-to-R/modules/getting%20started/first-r/), donde en la parte de swirl, hay un enlace para descargar el curso. Una vez descargado el curso e instalado el paquete swirl(), he procedido a instalar el curso tal y como indica en la guía:

```
library(swirl)
install_course_zip(""C:Users/sergi/Desktop/R/R Basics/swirl_courses-master.zip", multi=TRUE)
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error in unzip(path, list = TRUE) :
> zip file 'C:Users/sergi/Desktop/R/R Basics/swirl_courses-master.zip' cannot be opened

He probado a cambiar la ubicación del archivo sin éxito, y las soluciones que he consultado, hacen referencia a los cursos precargados en el paquete y eligiendo un programa en concreto, como por ejemplo:

```
install_course_zip("~/Downloads/swirl_courses-master.zip", multi=TRUE, which_course="R Programming")
```

Sin embargo, lo que yo quiero es instalar el curso y poder seguirlo, no solo descargar un curso.

Espero que me haya podido explicar bien y que me puedan echar una mano.

Gracias de antemano!

Sergio Lahera

Comment: Prueba modificando el path `C:\Users\sergi\Desktop\R\R Basics\swirl_courses-master.zip`